# How to sum pairs of values in a List in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

Lets say I have a List:

```
val list = List(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

How to sum each element with the next one to create a List of summed values of pairs? In my example I want to get:

```
List(4, 7, 9, 11)
```

What operations should I write to do this in a functional fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so after a bit of search I found the `sliding(...)` function:

```
val list = List(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
list.sliding(2).toSeq.map(_.sum) //List(4, 7, 9, 11)
```

And this works well

Comment: Another approach that works great with lists is: `(list lazyZip list.tail).map { case (x, y) => x + y }`

Comment: `.tail` will crash if the list is empty. You can use `.drop(1)` if you want to return an empty list instead.